# Проблема с OpenCV либой

Tags: python, flask, opencv

В общем проблема такова: есть IP камера, для получения rtsp потока использую либу OpenCV. Суть проблемы, видео очень и очень медленное на таймере камеры один фрейм идет раз в 3-4 секунды. Юзается фласк вреймворк, вот код:

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0 + cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
def gen_frames(camera):
while True:
    succes, frame = camera.read()   
    if not succes:
        flash('cam disabled')
        break
    else:
        ret, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        frame = buffer.tobytes()
        
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
             b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n'+frame+b'\r\n') 
    #time.sleep(1)          
    
@app.route('/video_feed')   
def video_feed():   
  cam1 = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://login:pwd@ip/cam/realmonitor?channel=1&subtype=0')
  cam1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS,25)
  flash(cam1.get(5))
  return Response(gen_frames(cam1),mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')
```

Comment: Так проблема в настройках камеры, а не в коде, разве нет?

Comment: нет, уже крутится один скрипт на серваке с такой же rtsp ссылкой и нормально все

Comment: В таком случае посмотрите сколько времени занимают операции с изображением

Answer (score 1):

Все исправилось, был мой косяк камера слушала 554 порт на внутриннем IP а я долбился на 553 порт